# Error when trying to insert an extended entity: invalid column index

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, observer-pattern, jpa-2.1

I have two entities for two classes. First is an extended class of the second (Observer pattern):
The child:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue("User")
@Table(name="SCH.USER")
public class User extends Observer implements Serializable{
    ...fields...
}
```

And the father:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) 
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name="SCH.OBSERVER")
public abstract class Observer implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "OBSERVER_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "NEXO.SEQ_OBSERVER", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "OBSERVER_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="ID_OBSERVER")
    private Long idObserver;

    @Column(name = "DISCRIMINATOR", nullable=false, length=20)
    private String discriminator;
}
```

Since I upgraded JPA 2.0 to JPA 2.1 I cannot persist the child entity:
em.persist(userInstance);
Which generates the next SQL:

```
insert 
into
    NEXO.OBSERVER
    (DISCRIMINATOR, ID_OBSERVER) 
values
    ('User', ?)
```

And gets the resulting error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: invalid column index
```

I am pretty sure this behavior change has been produced by the upgrade to JPA 2.1

Comment: What was the SQL it used prior to the upgrade?  Shouldn't the discriminator mapping be read-only, as it is supposed to be controlled by Java inheritance?  Try marking it as insertable=false, updatable=false

Comment: Please post the stacktrace (at least the relevant part). And specify the Hibernate version. I would guess that it has to do with using the DiscrimatorColumn as field - I don't think that this is supported explicitly anywhere (especially for a modifiable field). If you really need to read the discriminator value, you could use a `@Formula` instead - or you have a method `getDiscriminator()` that you implement for every subclass of Observer. And you don't need to define the `InheritanceType` twice - only use it for the root entity.

Comment: Both of you are right! Problem was on discriminator mapping. I added insertable=false, updatable=false and it works! I would give you the "best answer" check if I could.

Comment: insertable=false is ridiculous (though correct). Since the value is NOT defined on DB side, in MUST come as part of INSERT. Hence insertable=false does not make sense :) Look in the manual for @Column for this property: "Whether the column is included in SQL INSERT statements generated by the persistence provider."

Answer (score 2):

@Chris is right. When I upgrade from Jboss7 to Wildfly10, noticed this error and fixed by updating discriminator

> @Column(name = "INPUT_TYPE", nullable = false, length = 6, insertable = false, updatable = false)
>       public String getInputType() {
>           return inputType;
>       }

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem:

> ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - The column index is out of range: 2,
>   number of columns: 1

When I upgraded the JPA version to add the following two attributes to the discriminator column:

`insertable = false` and `updatable = false`

Earlier this was the default.